# Parsing a string with named sections and a key-value pair on each line

Tags: java, strings, parsing

I have a response String as shown below which I need to parse it and store it my class. Format is shown below:

- task name followed by this dotted line `-------------`  which is also fixed
- and then just below `key:value` pair. It can have many key value pair

Below is the response string.

```
abc-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4932152

def-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4932216

ghi-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4874588

pqr-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4874748
```

Below is my class:

```
public class NameMetrics {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> metrics;

    // setters and getters

}
```

In the above class, `name` should be `abc` and `metrics` map should have `Load` as the key and `79008` as the value and same with other `key:value` pairs. Below is the code I have.

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(response));
NameMetrics current = null;
Map<String, String> metricsHolder = null;
List<NameMetrics> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
  String s = reader.readLine();
  if (s == null) {
    break;  // end reached
  }
  if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
    continue;  // Skip empty line
  }
  int cut = s.indexOf(':');
  if (cut == -1) {
    cut = s.indexOf('-');
    if (cut == -1) {
      continue;
    }
    metricsHolder = new HashMap<String, String>();
    current = new NameMetrics();
    current.setName(s.substring(0, cut));
    result.add(current);
  } else if (current != null) {
    metricsHolder.put(s.substring(0, cut), s.substring(cut + 1));
    current.setMetrics(metricsHolder);
  }
}
```

I'd like a code review to see whether this can be improved in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code is very good: it reads easily, it is properly indented and clean. I am sure one could come up with a complicated regular expression for parsing this String but using a `StringReader` like you have done is simple and effective. It is dynamic with regard to the number of elements to put in the map.

I only have a couple of comments:

- You are trimming each line only to determine if they are blank with

  ```
  if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
      continue;  // Skip empty line
  }
  ```

  If you expect lines to have spaces to trim then you could do it all the time.
- Instead of having a `setMetrics` method that takes a map, I would have a `addMetric` method that adds a key/value pair into the map.

  ```
  public void addMetric(String key, String value) {
      metrics.put(key, value);
  }
  ```

  This way, you don't need to build the map yourself in the `while` loop.
- To prevent from `NullPointerException`, it is a good idea to always initiaze maps and lists when they are in instance variables. You can do it inline like the following:

  ```
  public class NameMetrics {

      private String name;
      private Map<String, String> metrics = new HashMap<>();

  }
  ```

  or in the default constructor.
- The variable `s` in `String s = reader.readLine();` could have a better name, like `line`.
- The `while(true)` loop with an explicit break works correctly, but it might be easier to follow with the traditional pattern `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {`.

With those couples changes, you can have:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(response));
NameMetrics current = null;
List<NameMetrics> result = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        continue; // Skip empty line
    }
    int cut = line.indexOf(':');
    if (cut == -1) {
        cut = line.indexOf('-');
        if (cut == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        current = new NameMetrics();
        current.setName(line.substring(0, cut));
        result.add(current);
    } else if (current != null) {
        current.addMetric(line.substring(0, cut), line.substring(cut + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First, I'd like to point out that if are you storing this from your program and reading it back from a file later, [you'd be better off Serializing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293991/how-to-write-and-read-java-serialized-objects-into-a-file). But since you're being given this file, let's move on.

### Infinite Loops

It's generally discouraged to use `while(true)` loops. It's not particularly *bad* ([in fact it's sometimes better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850380/are-whiletrue-loops-so-bad)), but it's always best to look for an alternative for readability sake. Instead, let's use `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)`.

### Initializing variables as `null`

I also see you initialized a few variables as null, but that isn't necessary since it's implied for classes. (Also note primitive variables are implied as 0 during initialization).

### Using the output format to your advantage

You also have a `cut` variable that gets the index of the tokens, and then skips the line if it's blank. However, we know that the output is always going to be grouped into three lines, and we always know what those lines are going to be. We also know the data you really want is going to be the first three characters for the name, and everything after the first five characters for the tokens. Let's use that and make everything clear!

### Putting it all together

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(response));
NameMetrics current;
Map<String, String> metricsHolder;
List<NameMetrics> result = new ArrayList<>();

String name, load, peak;

String nameline;
while ((nameline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    name = nameLine.substring(0, 3);
    load = reader.readLine().substring(5);
    peak = reader.readLine().substring(5);
    reader.readline(); //eat empty line

    current = new NameMetrics();
    metricsHolder = new HashMap<>();    //No need to repeat the stuff inside the diamond operator
    metricsHolder.put("Load", load);
    metricsHolder.put("Peak", peak);

    current.setName(name);
    current.setMetrics(metricsHolder);
    result.add(current);
}
```

### Handling varying keys and names

When there are a variable number of keys, we still know that they're all generally in the same format of the name followed dashes, then a list of `key:value` lines, then a blank line. We can still use this to our advantage as follows:

```
String name;
String[] mapValues;

final int KEY = 0, VALUE = 1;
String nameline, keyLine;
while ((nameline = reader.readLine().trim()) != null) {    //Loop until the end of the file
    name = nameLine.substring(0, nameLine.indexOf("-") + 1); //Plus because substring excludes last index

    metricsHolder = new HashMap<>();    //No need to repeat the stuff inside the diamond operator
    while (!(keyLine = reader.readLine().trim()).isEmpty()) {   //Loop until block ends with an empty line
        mapValues = reader.readLine().split(":");   //Split key:value format
        metricsHolder.put(mapValues[KEY], mapValues[VALUE]);
    }

    current = new NameMetrics();
    current.setName(name);
    current.setMetrics(metricsHolder);
    result.add(current);
}
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that there are only 2 values to put in the map.

Comment: In actual example, it can have more than two values that I need to put in the map. `Load` and `Peak` was just an example, it can have more `key:value` pairs.

Comment: That's true. As long as there are always the same number of values though, it's an easy update. We'd need more info from the OP to know if it's variable or not.

Comment: I don't know what `keys` might be beforehand so it has to be dynamic. In general depending on `response` variable, it should load `key:value` pairs in a map, no matter how many are there.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle a variable number of keys instead

Comment: Now it assumes that there is an empty line before each new group :)

Comment: Sure, but so did his code, and so did his example. In order for any parsing to be possible, we have to know how may lines there are, or there has to be some unique delimiter we can use. Whatever the delimiter is, we can take advantage of it either with `.isEmpty()` for a blank line or `.equals(delim)` if it's something else for some reason :)

Comment: I don't think the original code assumes an empty line before each group. A new group is only started when a line containing a `'-'` is detected, whatever is before (I tested without the empty line and it still works).

Comment: We'd need a confirmation from @user1950349 but his code had   `if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
    continue;  // Skip empty line
  }` and his example text had a blank line between each line

Comment: @BrainFRZ Yes all empty lines are skipped but the fact that there is an empty line is not the trigger for the start of a new group. The new group starts when `cut = s.indexOf('-');` is different then `-1`. If you run the code in the question on the example data but without empty lines, the result is still the same.

Comment: Again, we'd need to know from the OP, but his sample text suggests that there's a blank line between each block. Bottom line, since I'm getting the "extended discussion" thing, his code can be vastly improved no matter what to not need the `continue`s and nested if-checks, and my version also tells you exactly what's going on where with variable names instead of unnamed substrings. It's also separated the parsing of data from the assignment to the metrics and result objects, where both yours and his have assignments in two places.